Whats the best approach to set LOCALE_ID in an i18n SSR Angular 19 app?
Whats the best approach to set LOCALE_ID in an i18n SSR Angular 19 app?
I can set it on the server (app.server.config.ts) by setting this DI token:
{
  provide: LOCALE_ID,
  useFactory: () => {
    const req = inject(REQUEST, { optional: true});
    return req.path.split('/')[1]; // e.g. /en or /de
  },
  deps: [REQUEST],
},

This works! But now what when the client takes over (CSR)? I assume there is no way for the client to have access providers defined in app.server.config.ts, right?
So that means I need to provide it again in the client. I can do that, e.g. by setting it to navigator.language or parsing it from window.path - but it just feels dirty doing it on client and server, is this really the right approach? What's the best practice here?

...Wait, or do I not need to set it at all? Is it already taken care of by the localize: true in angular.json? At least in earlier versions, I remember it was necessary to set the LOCALE_ID in the server.ts, that's why I'm asking....

When localization is enabled, Angular automatically includes the locale data and sets the LOCALE_ID token, see the docs. So you don't need to set the LOCALE_ID by yourself.

Thanks, that's what I assumed! But is this a new feature? In earlier versions we always had to manually set it, such as in this example: https://github.com/lostium/ssr-i18n-angular17/blob/main/server.ts#L57

@Patric I can't tell for sure, but it is possible that in previous versions such a hack was necessary. Angular has improved the SSR features a lot recently.
